# Best hash table for insertion and lookup only

Tags: data-structures

I want to make a hash table that allows insertion and lookup only. Once something is in the table, it is in for good, unless you make a new hash table and refill the contents. Is there any algorithms/data structures that are more suited for this (over say B-tree/RB-tree/LLRB-tree)? Better would be like - faster insertion and lookup times, or can be sharded easier, or smaller overhead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you know (roughly) how many times each item will be looked up (and these frequencies are not uniform) then you could use Knuth's algorithm ([free pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20110515053419/http://www.springerlink.com/content/uj8j384065436q61/)) for finding an optimal tree that will make the more frequently-accessed items closer to the top (and so are faster to access). Each node in this tree would be a hash code (used for navigating the tree) and a pointer to the actual item. I don't know of any implementations of this algorithm, though...